# Using #undef before #define

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

In many places I see the usage of undefine macro before defining the same macro. For example:

```
#undef FORMULA
#ifdef SOMETHING
#define FORMULA 1
#else 
#define FORMULA 2
#endif
```

What for the `#undefine FORMULA` used?
I may guess that it deals with the case when the macro was already defined before. But isn't the new definition overrides the old one? Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A macro name currently defined cannot be redefined with a *different* definition (see below), so `#undef` allows that macro name to be redefined with a different definition.

Here's the relevant legalese:

Both C and C++ Standards (same wording):

> A macro definition lasts (independent of block structure) until a corresponding **#undef** directive is encountered or (if none is encountered) until the end of the preprocessing translation unit.

Slight differences in wording, same meaning:

> C Standard (N1256), §6.10.3/2:
>   An identifier currently defined as an object-like macro shall not be redefined by another **#define** preprocessing directive unless the second definition is an object-like macro definition and the two replacement lists are identical. Likewise, an identifier currently defined as a function-like macro shall not be redefined by another **#define**  preprocessing directive unless the second definition is a function-like macro definition that has the same number and spelling of parameters, and the two replacement lists are identical.
>
> C++ Standard (N3337) §16.3/2
>    An identifier currently defined as an object-like macro may be redefined by another **#define** preprocessing directive provided that the second definition is an object-like macro definition and the two replacement lists are identical, otherwise the program is ill-formed. Likewise, an identifier currently defined as a function-like macro may be redefined by another **#define** preprocessing directive provided that the second definition is a function-like macro definition that has the same number and spelling of parameters, and the two replacement lists are identical, otherwise the program is ill-formed.

Same wording in both Standards:

> Two replacement lists are identical if and only if the preprocessing tokens in both have the same number, ordering, spelling, and white-space separation, where all white-space separations are considered identical.

So:

```
#define X(y)   (y+1)
#define X(z)   (z+1)   // ill-formed, not identical
```

IMHO, using `#undef` is generally dangerous due to the scoping rules for preprocessor macros.  I'd prefer to get a warning or error from the preprocessor and come up with a different preprocessor macro rather than have some translation unit silently accept a wrong macro definition that introduces a bug into the program.  Consider:

```
// header1.h
#undef  PORT_TO_WRITE_TO
#define PORT_TO_WRITE_TO    0x400

// header2.h
#undef  PORT_TO_WRITE_TO
#define PORT_TO_WRITE_TO    0x410
```

and have a translation unit `#include` both headers.  No warning, probably not the intended result.

Comment: I totally agree with suggestion to get error instead of silent act!

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the new definition overrides all previous. But there is corresponding warning message. With `#undef` you have no warnings.

Answer (score 0):

> But isn't the new definition overrides the old one?

Yes, it does (when your compiler allows it). However, redefining a macro results in a compiler warning, which using `#undefine` lets you avoid.

This may be important in programming shops with strict rules on compiler warnings - for example, by requiring all production code to be compiled with `-Werror` flag, which treats all warnings as errors.

Comment: Redefining a macro is not allowed by the C and C++ standards. Whether the message is delivered as a warning or an error, it's wrong.

Comment: @Potatoswatter Redefining is allowed by both standards, but all redefinitions are required to be identical. A message delivered as an error results in failed translation, so it's spot on as far as standard compliance is concerned.

Comment: Repetition of the same definition isn't really redefinition, and it will not produce any diagnostic message in any reasonable compiler. No compiler I've seen does an error by default. And, `-Werror` usually renders the compiler nonconforming.

Answer (score 0):

`#undef` removes the macro, so the name is free to be defined again.

If the macro was never defined in the first place, `#undef` has no effect, so there's no downside. `#undef` … `#define` should be read as replacing any potential previous definition, but not to imply that it must already be defined.

Popular compilers do allow you to skip the `#undef`, but this is not allowed by the official standard ISO C and C++ language specifications. It is not portable to do so.